# simple function calling javascript

Tags: javascript

See the following code (also at http://jsfiddle.net/zpw015hq/1/).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
    <script>
      function me(tag, text) {
        document.write("<h1>" + tag + "");
        document.write("<p>" + text + "");    
      }    
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script>
      me("5", "i am heading");
      me("p", "i am text");    
    </script>
  </body>    
</html>
```

In the result you can see that I have not added a break between "5" and "i am heading" but its output is coming in two different lines. Why?

Secondly i have not finished the `<h1>` tag with `</h1>`. So why does it look like that? In the heading if i removed `<h1>` then it becomes like a simple text.

Comment: please reformat your post.

Comment: Paragraphs and h1 are *block-level* elements, so you're getting a new line. Nothing magical going on.

Comment: _"I have not finished the tag `<h1>` with `</h1>` so why does it look like that?"_ All major browsers now complete your formatting errors: you can't put a `<p>` inside an header so the browser fixed your error adding a `</h1>` right before your `<p>`

Comment: I agree with @HunanRostomyan, try replacing the tags with an inline nature element like `<span>` and see the difference. Besides `document.write()`, seriously??

Comment: Answers below (they do all address only parts of the issue, but all the explanation is there eventually), but the real question remains, what are you trying to achieve? What is it that _should_ come out?

Answer (score 2):

Document.write will replace the whole HTML document. Track an element via ID using jquery and set the html:

```
$("#test").html("foo");
```

Comment: `document.write` does not replace the whole HTML.

Comment: The write() method writes HTML expressions or JavaScript code to a document.

The write() method is mostly used for testing: If it is used after an HTML document is fully loaded, it will delete all existing HTML.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_write.asp

Comment: @LucasRodriguez Right, so you should have said "Document.write _in an onload event_ will replace ..." Anyway, that is not the cause of the OP's confusion. (or maybe it is, seeing as the code in the question does not use onload.)

Answer (score 1):

You don't close h1 and p tag. 
Here is code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
   <script>
    function me(tag,text){
       document.write("<h1>"+tag+"</h1>"+"");
       document.write("<p>"+text+"</p>"+"");

  }
   </script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
  me("5","i am heading");
  me("p","i am text");
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

It will work.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that it is not by purpose, but happened by (a copy paste?) mistake. Your code does not look correct as it is not closing the tags (`h1` and `p`)

```
function me(tag,text){
       document.write("<h1>" + tag + "</h1>"); //closed h1
       document.write("<p>" + text + "</p>");  //closed p
}
```